# MySQL dump with dash at the beginning of a database name

Tags: php, mysql

Does anyone know how to get mysqldump to work when the database has a dash as the first character of the name? Ex: -s-oddly-named-db

I need to dump this database for an archive for a client, but I have never seen someone create a database with a dash as the first character. Within MySQL itself I can use back-ticks to "use" it and everything works just fine, but I cannot get mysqldump to work.

`mysqldump -p --databases '-s-oddly-named-db'`

Gives me the response of:
`mysqldump: unknown option '-s'`

Comment: Can you temporarily rename the database? I think fear this may be your only option if you must use mysqldump.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

by using `--`

for example :

`mysqldump -u root -pXXXX --databases -- -xDatabase`

more about what does `--` means from `man bash` :

> Unless otherwise noted, each builtin command documented in this
>   section as accepting options preceded by - accepts -- to signify the
>   end of the options.

**EDIT** thanks to [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) comment

Using `--` to signal the end of options is a common convention, which is implemented by the `getopts()` library function. That's presumably why it works with `mysdqldump`, even though it's not mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Why are you quoting `bash` documentation? This isn't a bash built-in? The answer is otherwise correct.

Comment: Using `--` to signal the end of options is a common convention, which is implemented by the `getopts()` library function. That's presumably why it works with `mysdqldump`, even though it's not mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: i just quoted bash because i can't find any reference in the `man` for the `--` feature , if you got this please mention it .

Comment: I did not have to specify --databases, the following worked just fine. Thank you.

```mysqldump -p -- -s-oddly-named-db```